# Comparacion de Fechas

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Amigos que tal, tengo un problema con mi programa. Resulta que en mi base de datos (mysql) indico los dias y las horas en las que una tarea ingresada sera ejecutada. Y mediante un proceso php voy haciendo correr los procesos que cumplen con esa condicion y he alli el problema.

Actualmente, si tengo que una tarea sera ejecutada de Lunes a Viernes, desde las 08:30 hasta las 19:00 hrs al momento de comparar las horas me falla la condicion.

```
 $horainicio= "08:30";
 $horafin = "19:00";
 //OBTENER FECHA Y HORA
 $time = strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time() ); //FECHA y HORA
 $hora = strftime("%H:%M", time() ); //HORA 

 if(($horaini <= $hora) and ($hora <= $horaterm)) {
    echo "El proceso correra \n";
} else { 
    echo "El proceso no correra \n";
}
```

Sin embargo el problema se presenta cuando son mas de las 12 de la noche, puesto que las 08:30 es mayor a las Hora Actual que serian las 05:00, las 01:00, etc.
Entonces trate de solucionarlo convirtiendo la hora a timestamp pero, el caso es lo mismo, puesto que mi proceso debe tomar la fecha actual y al consultar todos los dias la base de datos, debe insertar la fecha actual a la hora (08:30) la cual seria la misma fecha que tiene el sistema actual, por ende seguirá siendo mayor. =/

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: tienes bien configurado tus zonas horarias de php y los campos date de mysql ?

Comment: si, todo bien configurado , php server, y msyql

Comment: El proceso se debe ejecutar siempre y cuando estemos entre las 8:30 y las 19:00?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes una confusion, como estas usando string obviamente no te van a dar los resultados, puedes usar la clases [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php), un Ejemplo:

```
$fecha_actual = new DateTime("now");

$fecha_inicio = new DateTime("now");
$fecha_inicio->setTime("9","30");


$fecha_fin = new DateTime("now");
$fecha_fin->setTime("19","00");

var_dump ($fecha_inicio < $fecha_actual && $fecha_actual < $fecha_fin);
```

[puedes ver el ejemplo en linea](http://codepad.org/oI83xrPA)

si quieres saber si el dia paso solo debes comparar los dias, seria algo como:

```
echo($fecha_inicio->format('d') == $fecha_actual->format("d"));
```

Comment: he transformado las fechas con el horario a timestamp, sin embargo sigue igual. las 08:30 es mayor a las 06.
El tema es identificar que las 06:30 hrs corresponden al dia siguiente, no al mismo dia. Pero hacer eso significaria que despues de las 00:00 horainicio tendria que ser -1 dia. Es la unica forma que se me ocurre en que las 08:30 puedan ser menor que las 01:00 am del dia siguiente.

Tu codigo tampoco me sirvio:

Comment: la ventaja de usar dateTime es que tienes acceso al dia actualizare mi respuesta

Comment: Disculpa, pero no entendi como comparas los dias, veras yo solo tengo en mi base la hora .. por ejemplo las 08:30 y un proceso toma esa hora y la compara con la actual. Al correr el proceso, tomara el dia actual (en que esta corriendo), sin embargo a mi hora (tomada desde la base de datos), habria que asignarle un dia, para hacer la comparacion.
De lo contrario la fecha que obtiene el proceso sera siempre la actual, y al setear la hora, permanecera con la misma fecha o no? Me explico ?

Comment: te entiendo, como puedes observar cuando hago new DateTime("now"); es el dia de hoy solo actualizo la hora asumiendo siempre que el dia es el mismo